# Parse Postscript string into a int

Tags: postscript

I have a string in the stack in PostScript, and I would like to pop this string and then convert it into an int data type.

This is so that I can do an operation on the value which cannot be done as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The 'cvi' operator takes a parameter of type num (integer or real number) or string and returns an integer on the stack. See the 3rd edition PostScript Language Reference Manual, page 566.

Answer (score 0):

@user2558542 for string to integer you could use:
(yourstring) {} forall

for array to integers you could try:
[ yourarray ] aload pop

Comment: `forall` just gives you the byte values. This could be made to work by testing the range 48-57 (ascii digits), subtracting 48 and then a base-10 conversion of the resulting list. But `cvi` does this. Also `token` can do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to convert a string representing an integer into an integer object.

Simplest, use `cvi`:

```
(123) cvi  % => 123
```

You can also use the `token` operator which will convert representations of any basic object (except literal arrays). It returns the trailing substring, the new object, and a boolean which will be false if the conversion fails.

```
(123) token  % => () 123 true
```

You can also make the string executable and execute it which will invoke `token` internally.

```
(123) cvx exec  % => 123
```

Or you could iterate through the ascii values and compute the result manually.

```
(123)
[ exch
  {
    48 sub
  } forall
]  % => [ 1 2 3 ]
0 exch {
  exch 10 mul add
} forall  % ie. ((0*10 + 1)*10 + 2)*10 + 3  => 123
```

Or, combining the two loops and eliminating the array.

```
(123)
0 exch { 48 sub exch 10 mul add } forall  % => 123
```